# Dropdown control in dynamic view in Asp.net mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a model

```
public class DynamicFields   
{
    public string propertyName { get; set; }
    public string propertyType { get; set; }
}
```

This will be populated as List in my controller.

Now i need to render controls dynamically in View based on propertyType text value. If value is  "TextBox" I need to render textbox control. So I have used editorfor control.

View,

```
@model IEnumerable<DynamicFields>

@foreach(var field in Model)
{
        @Html.LabelFor(model => field.propertyName)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => field.propertyName, field.propertyType)
}
```

I don't know how to handle this in case of DropDownList.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This is assuming you want to display a DropDownList instead of a textbox **on page render.**

```
@model IEnumerable<DynamicFields>

@foreach (var field in Model)
{
    Html.LabelFor(model => field.propertyName)
    if (field.propertyType == "Textbox") 
    {
        Html.EditorFor(model => field.propertyName)
    }
    else
    {
        Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.propertyName, field.propertyType)
    }
}
```

If you want it to change on the client side depending on what the user picks in the dropdown, then you have to use javascript/jquery.